# Calculate velocity of a mechanism

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I have tried many times to solve this problem in different ways but with nos success:
The angular velocity of the shaft AB is 3rad/s counterclockwise. Calculate the velocity of the shafts BD and DE.

Could someone please show me how it should be done?

[[image: 1]]

expected answers: 0 rad/s, 2 rad/s

Comment: Is it 0 or 0.66 for bd

Comment: What do you mean? The shafts length?

Comment: Angular velocity

Comment: this angular velocity is not given. But according to the answers it is 0 (for some mysterious reason)

Comment: I am talking about answer is it 0.6 for Ab so approx $0$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: 
I don't know because I don't know how to get the final answer. I only know the final result because it is given in the manual I am using.

Comment: @privetDruzia: what is the manual?

Answer (score 0):

Hint $\omega=\frac{v}{r}$ you can calculate $r$ by pythaogoras theorem for BD same for DE  and no need of pythagoras theorem there

Comment: Yes indeed I did something similar to that, but didn't work...
http://imgur.com/PsFg73Y
And Vbd is already incorrect, so Vde will be too

Comment: see lets talk in SI units i e (meters ) convert mm to meters and you get it .

Comment: I think that converting to SI units would still not do the trick. Could you please post your method to clarify your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In the given position, the velocity of $B$ and $D$ are vertical, the first one tangent to the circle of center $A$ and passing though $B$, the second tangent to the circle of center $E$ and passing through $D$.

The center of rotation of $BD$ is at the intersection of the lines perpendicular to this two velocities, but being the velocities parallel, also the two perpendicular lines are parallel, so there is no intersection, and this mean that $BD$ does not rotate, but translate, so its angular velocity is $0\text{rad/s}$ and $v_B=v_D$.

Furthermore, given that $v_B=r_{AB}\omega_{AB}$ and $v_D=r_{ED}\omega_{ED}$, then
$$
r_{AB}\omega_{AB}=r_{ED}\omega_{ED}\implies \omega_{ED}=\frac{r_{AB}}{r_{ED}}\omega_{AB}=\frac{150\text{mm}}{225\text{mm}}3\text{rad/s}=2\text{rad/s}
$$